# Excel SUM function

Tags: excel

I have two columns, first column is price, second is kg. I would like to have a sum function in the cell (let say cell B2) that can tell total money as below example, what kind of sum function should help me in this case?

```
Total $        Cell B2 = 3*2 + 1*3 + 5*1 ......= 14

Price          Kg

2              3
3              1
1              5
...            ...
```

Comment: the function `sumproduct`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
=sumproduct(A4:A6, B4:B6)
```